# Strange positioning error with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my code:

http://www.bootply.com/iWR392T4aU

If you click on the mobile / smartphone view, it should look like this:

[image]

However, if you enlarge the window so that it goes to the desktop view, then quickly resize it back to mobile view, the button is out of position:

[image]

I inspected the element to try to figure out the cause of the problem but I couldn't find anything. It has no margin so I have no idea what's causing it to be pushed down like that.

Comment: your mobile users won't change the page to desktop view right?

Comment: yeah you make a good point. it probably wont ever be an issue. it will continue to annoy me forever though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by playing around on bootply, I can see that it's the "i" element with a class of .contact-3. This is set to display: none, but in one of the media queries (line 111), it is set to display: inline-block. It's increasing the height of the navbar to 70px from 50px.

Adding

```
    i.fa-envelope.contact-3 {
        display: none;
    }
```

in that media query seemed to fix it.